# lit-element wait for nested shadow element to render

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, lit

I'm trying to access the shadow element to provide default value

```
<my-element>
  #shadowroot(open)
    <styled-input> // not my own, so I cannot modify its internal logic
      #shadowroot(open)
        <input />  // trying to access this native html input element
    </styled-input> 
</my-element>
```

When using life cycle `firstUpdated`, I see that `<styled-input>` is created, but its shadow is not rendered yet.

```js
  protected firstUpdated(): void {
    console.log(this.shadowRoot);
    // <styled-input></styled-input>
  }
```

I can get the `<input />` element using `setTimeout`, which is not ideal.

How can I wait for the `<styled-input>`'s firstUpdated without modifying logic in `<styled-input>`?

Comment: Why using `setTimeout`, is not ideal for you?

Comment: You have to wait till the JavaScript EventLoop is empty, so you know all lightDOM of <styled-input> is parsed... tada.. setTimeout does that wait for you; but if you want to go the more bloated way, feel free to go the Promisses, rAF or other ways. Maybe look at how Lit source code how it does these situations....oh boy.. they use.. setTimeout